# SugarCRM detailview calculated field with subpanel data

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have two custom modules that have a one-to-many relation ship A->B
I'm trying to calculate field at editview for module A "total price", based on all "price" (sum) of subpanel for module B.

It's is possible to do in detailview, not using logichooks

Answer (score 0):

In the Studio, open the field(total price) of module A whose value you want to update, add a calculation formula. In the formula editor, select rollup.   You can select the rollup type as Sum, your module B and the field in module B whose sum is to be populated in total price.